# shell script (macOS): print escaped Unicode character from a plist string

Tags: bash, macos, unicode, plist, defaults

In a shell script I'm reading strings from the Info.plist in application bundles, in this example from the Copyright key, whereas $FILEPATH is the path to an application bundle, e.g. `/Applications/TextEdit.app`

```
#!/bin/bash  
PLIST=$(/usr/bin/defaults read "$FILEPATH/Contents/Info.plist")
COPYRIGHT=$(echo "$PLIST" | /usr/bin/awk -F" = " '/NSHumanReadableCopyright/{print $2}' RS=';' | /usr/bin/sed 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/')
echo "Copyright: $COPYRIGHT"
```

Note: I'm not reading the key directly, which would be easier, of course; it's read into the variable PLIST, so the script can read other keys as well later on, and doesn't have to use the `defaults` command over and over.

Now the output is (for example) `Copyright: Copyright \\U00a9 1995-2015, Apple Inc.\\nAll rights reserved.`

Obviously the copyright sign \U00a9 was escaped, as was the line break, but how can I solve this problem so that the shell script actually prints out the string as it was meant to, i.e. with copyright sign and line break?

PS: at the end I would probably remove the line break, but as the first step I'd want to echo the whole thing as intended.

Answer (score 3):

I would to use `plutil` instead of the `defaults`. The:

```
plist="/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/Info.plist"
plutil -p - < "$plist"
```

will print

```
... some lines deleted...
  "DTSDKName" => "macosx10.12internal"
  "DTXcode" => "0800"
  "NSHumanReadableCopyright" => "Copyright © 1995-2016, Apple Inc.
All rights reserved."
  "DTSDKBuild" => "16C7"
  "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion" => "English"
... other delted lines ...
```

the `-p` mean *human readable format* - so hard to process. Therefore, is better convert the `plist` to `json`, for example:

```
plutil -convert json -r -o - - < "$plist"
```

the `-r` mean *convert to human-readable `JSON`* , e.g.

```
{
  "CFBundleName" : "TextEdit",
  "DTSDKName" : "macosx10.12internal",
  "DTXcode" : "0800",
  "NSHumanReadableCopyright" : "Copyright © 1995-2016, Apple Inc.\nAll rights reserved.",
  "DTSDKBuild" : "16C7",
  "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion" : "English",
  "CFBundleVersion" : "329",
```

Now you can easily filter out the `NSHumanReadableCopyright` key, even using `awk`, but it is much better to use some *real* tool.

Mac by default has installed `perl` and also the `JSON::PP` module. So the:

```
plist="/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/Info.plist"
plutil -convert json -r -o - - < "$plist" |\
/usr/bin/perl -0777 -CSDA -MJSON::PP -MEncode -E '$p=decode_json(encode_utf8(<>));say $p->{NSHumanReadableCopyright}'
```

will output

```
Copyright © 1995-2016, Apple Inc.
All rights reserved.
```

Edit:
tested the whole as one long line from the comment:

```
plist="/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/Info.plist"; jplist=$(/usr/bin/plutil -convert json -r -o - "$plist"); copyright=$(echo "$jplist" | /usr/bin/perl -0777 -CSDA -MJSON::PP -MEncode -E '$p=decode_json(encode_utf8(<>));say $p->{NSHumanReadableCopyright}'); echo "$copyright"
```

and prints OK...

Comment: I might suggest quoting `"/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/Info.plist"` ( just in case there might be a space when dealing with other app names, or if the $plist variable didn't happen to be ).

Comment: That's working great. Thank you. What doesn't work, however, is putting the JSON plutil output into a variable, let's say jplist, and then echoing that and piping it to the perl command.

`jplist=$(/usr/bin/plutil -convert json -r -o - "$plist") ;`

`copyright=$(echo "$jplist" | /usr/bin/perl -0777 -CSDA -MJSON::PP -MEncode -E '$p=decode_json(encode_utf8(<>));say $p->{NSHumanReadableCopyright}') ;`

`echo "$copyright"`

(It's not a big deal because plutil + perl on its own seems to be fast enough.)

Comment: No, actually I tested it now, reading lots of plist keys with plutil + perl individually for every single key, and it's very slow compared to one single defaults read + echo & awk. So the plutil + perl combo is only good for specific keys that might pose problems with stdout.

Comment: Ah, didn't refresh & see the edit… will test it now. Thank you.

Comment: @JayB - what do you mean  with _every single key_? youre doing something other. The `JSON` is standardised format. I answered the question about the copyright - if you want do something other - ask a new question. :)

Comment: The issue at hand was printing out the Unicode, and that's what your plutil+perl solution does. But it's not not suited for reading many keys from a plist variable and printing them to output, because always calling perl for a simple plist key parsing is too slow; defaults + awk is definitely faster. But the Unicode thing is solved, so yeah, everything's fine. :)

Comment: @JayB looks like youre not really understand what the perl script does. It parses  the **whole** `JSON` - and could print out any number of keys (even all) in a single call - so without the need run it multiple times... but - nvermind - it is your project.. ;) :)

Comment: Well, I don't know perl, so I couldn't say. :)

Comment: Question: would you be able to use perl to parse the whole JSON, print out any number of keys, and write these keys to individual shell variables? That would be splendid, and I'd look into it.

Comment: @JayB - try ask a new question. Add all relevant goals. Do you need parse many plists, or only one? what keys do you need? (and why need assing them all to shell-variable...) etc... What do you mean with _too slow_ - how fast you need? :) Add some sample code, what you want achieve.  The worst thing what could happen - you will get no answer... :)

Comment: @JayB: You may accept the answer if it worked. That is the official way of saying Thank you here :)